# Lazy-loading of images in a listview or datalist in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listview

I have a page with few listview and a few datalist, which are bound to a objectdatasource.
I get the image URL from database and show those images.

Images are on my server inside one folder.

Can somebody guide me how to implement lazy-loading of images with the listview and datalist in my situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "LazyLoading" if you mean on browser they are loaded only when user scrolls the page ? (Check google image search for the exact functionality. The images are displayed gray and loaded only after the page is scrolled upto that part.)

You can use JQuery javascript with plugin LazyLoad plugin available at: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

OR

If you are not familiar with JQuery then http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=46393 this independent script may also help.

Comment: i found this link http://sumanrs.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/jquery-lazy-loading-images-no-scrolling/.  Will try this too.